# Aborted (core dumped) : Check failed: "image_tensor" has mis-matching actual and final data types (data_type=uint8, final_data_type=float)

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I am getting this error since so long, can anyone help in fixing this soon.

graph_def_file = "my_detection_model.pb"

input_arrays = ['image_tensor']
output_arrays = ['SecondStagePostprocessor/convert_scores']

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
    graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays, input_shapes={"image_tensor":[1,600,600,3]})

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open ("my_first_model.tflite", "wb") .write(tflite_model)